# dropshadow for transparent alert not working JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to add dropshadow to my alert box I am setting it's style to transparent and initOwner to my current stage. The shadow on the button is working, but not on the alert box. Why is the dropShadow in the .alertBox not working? Should I place the dropshadow somewhere else? This is how I am creating the alert:

```
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.initOwner(stage);
    alert.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    DialogPane dialog = alert.getDialogPane();
    dialog.setGraphic(null);
    dialog.getStyleClass().add("alertBox");
```

This is my css:

```
.alertBox{
    -fx-background-color: #2A2E37;
    -fx-border-color: #363b41;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,1.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 2 );

}
.alertBox > *.button-bar > *.container{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-pref-height: 50
}

.alertBox:header *.header-panel{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.alertBox:header *.header-panel *.label{
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-pref-height: 25;
    -fx-text-fill: #363b41;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0) , 0, 0.0 , 0 , 0 );
}
.alertBox > *.label.content{
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-text-fill: #bcbcbc;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-pref-height: 50;
    -fx-padding: 0,0,10,0;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,1.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 2 );
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.alertBox Button{
    -fx-text-fill: #bcbcbc;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,1.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 0);
    -fx-background-color: #2A2E37;
}
```

Edit:

```
    Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    Pane root = new FXMLLoader(LoggedFirstStyle.class.getResource("/FXML/logged-first.fxml")).load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(LoggedFirstStyle.class.getResource("/css/logged-first.css").toString());
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    stage = new Stage();
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    stage.setWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
    stage.setHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
    stage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
    stage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());
```

Comment: there is a lot of code missing in your example, so i can only guess here :D, hmm maybe your alert is overwritten by the dialogpanel ? can you try to change ".alertBox" to ".dialog-pane" in your css file :3

Comment: @CrissCrossCrass nothing changes in the style, when I change it to .dialog-pane. This is the how I create the alert and style it, what kind of code is missing?

Comment: for me iam missing the stage code stuff, how your code is implemented, MVC? Or just a simple JavaFX Application without controller? (if so, why the DialogPane?) how is your CSS File attached to your Applications...stuff like this...hmm i will check out tomorrow and write an answer, iam pretty sure there must be a working way :)

Comment: @CrissCrossCrass I updated the answer this is the way I create the stage load the fxml and the css. It is javaFx application connecterd to a rest api with apache

Comment: @CrissCrossCrass And I use controllers for the fxml elements and initialization

Answer (score 0):

here is very simple but working example for alert box with DropShadow, hope it helps!

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Drop Shadow!");
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        DialogPane dialog = alert.getDialogPane();
        dialog.setGraphic(null);
        dialog.setStyle(
                "-fx-background-color: #2A2E37; -fx-border-color: #363b41; -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,1.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 2 );"
        );
        root.getChildren().addAll(dialog);
        root.setStyle(
                "-fx-background-color: #ffffff;"
        );
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

[image: Outcome AlertBox Drop Shadow]

I can't get to work with CSS, i dunno why and don't have so much time to investigate the root cause sorry :)

Comment: Your example seems to work only if the dialog is added as a child to the root, but not if you do alert.show();